# How to use user input as an Quantifier in Regex in JS?

Tags: javascript, regex, quantifiers

My attempt was :

```
var re = new RegExp("\w{" + n + "}", "g");
```

But it didn't seems to work.

P.S. - I have searched several questions of Stackoverflow thinking it must have been asked before But I didn't find one, so I asked my question.

Comment: What is really what you want to do?

Comment: I want to split the string, into pairs according to the input (n) given by user.

Comment: But what have you tried so far? Do you have more code?

Comment: For example String is 'Divyansh' and n is 2 => ['Di','vy','an','sh'];

Comment: Just this in return statement `var arr = str.match(re);` where str is the variable having the string.

Comment: actually this should work as is, you forgot that \ is also the escape character in JS, so it becomes \\, but you could just use `.` instead of `\\w`

Comment: What do you exactly meant 'maraca' ? I have used \w to represent alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Yup, as @maraca says, you are missing a backslash. Maraca, why don't you add that answer? That is the correct solution and you are the one who "first" posted it.

Comment: Ok, but what do you do then with "hello world!" and length 3? this would return (hel, wor) then instead of (hel, lo , wor, ld!)...

Comment: @Mindastic because people are downvoting if the answer is too "easy".

Comment: It's strange I changed \w to . and the code worked :-\

Comment: @maraca: it doesn't make sense. If your answer is the correct one, i don't see why people would be downvoting it. Add the answer add you will have, at least, one upvote from me :P

Comment: Any help ?? I just figured out that my attempt to add users input to regex was correct other than the my code didn't worked. So how can I mark question as solved?? Because I don't want any downvotes on question??

Comment: And FYI \\w doesn't work as per my expectations :( I don't want to search '\w' in my string

Comment: @DivyanshBatham if that doesn't work, please add a concrete example of what you want to do because \\w is the correct answer to what you asked.

Comment: @DivyanshBatham What's always working is `[]` so maybe `[A-Za-z0-9_]` ?

Comment: You should put your entire question and code in your question, not in comments. If you need a 10-comment thread to clarify what you need, there's not enough info in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\` is not only the escape character in regex but also in JS strings. So when you create a regular expression from a string you need to escape it. This means that `\w` becomes `"\\w"` in a string and if you want to match a single `\` it would even become `"\\\\"`.

Instead of changing it to `\\w` you can also use `.` if you don't care about the characters or if the string was validated before.

Comment: `\ is not only the escape character in regex but also in JS strings` I didn't knew that earlier, any link where where I can learn about that is much appreciated ^_^

Comment: @DivyanshBatham I like this source http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html, but I usually already know what I'm looking for, should still give a good overview. To *test regex online* there are many sites, just enter the italic text in a search engine. PS: As Jan said, if you put the things you said in the comments in the question it is more likely to get upvoted.